# Creating an array from a constructor in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, constructor

So I've been trying to figure out how to populate an array with an object I have created in C#.  I found this code sample which explains a bit about what I need to do.

```
for (int i = 0;i<empArray.Length;i++)
       {
           empArray[i] = new Employee(i+5);
       }
```

But what happens if I pass more than one parameter into my constructor? Will this look any different? Like empArray[i] = new Employee(i, j, k); and so on. And if so how will read these objects out of the array, to say the Console. Would

```
Console.WriteLine(empArray[i])
```

do the trick if the object has more than one variable passed into it, or will I need a multi dimensional array? I apologize for all the questions, just a little new to C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters passed in to the constructor are simply information for the object to initialize itself. No matter how many parameters you pass in, only a single `Employee` object will come out, and that object will be put in `empArray[i]`.

You will always access the `Employee` objects using `empArray[<index>]` where index is an integer where 0 <= index < empArray.Length.

`Console.WriteLine` takes a string or any object with a `ToString()` method on it. So if the `Employee` object implements `ToString()`, then `Console.WriteLine(empArray[i])` will work. You might implement `ToString()` like this:

```
public string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName);
}
```

Comment: And if I wanted to access one of the classes methods from the empArray would I just do empArray[i].SomeMethod?

Comment: That is exactly right! `empArray[i]` returns the object at index `i`, so you can treat it as though you were dealing directly with that object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would work. In the statement array[i] the i is used as a reference to a position in a array, and has nothing to do with the actual contents of the object.